# How add 3rd party APIs to my Api.ai/Java ChatBot in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have a ChatBot using mainly Api.ai platform, and to use 3rd party services ( Translation, weather etc... ) I need to add external APIs for them to work. How can i add those APIs in my Eclipse Project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add JARs to your Eclipse project you have to add them to your build path. Follow the steps below

1. Right click on project > Build Path > Configure Build Path

[image]

2. Use `Add JARS` or `Add External JARS` to add the 3rd party libraries. Difference between the two options is that the first one only lets you select JARs inside project directory, whereas the second one allows you to select JARs in any directory.

[image]